# Strip tags in django view page django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a user with view only permission in a model with `richtextfield`, but when viewing the data on this particular user with only view permission, the data is not formatted in html. I know, below is how to strip tags when you want to strip tags in `list_display`,

```
def what_field(self, obj):
       return format_html(obj.what)
```

please see attached image.

[image]

**EDIT**

So, I was trying to use the django admin as the main page for the admin. I have a model where there is an `announcement model` with object like `what`, `when`, `where`, `who` etc.
When the admin is login and view the announcement model/table/form. there is no problem in view, since the admin page show the objects in the text field or in this case, in `richtextfield` using the `django-ckeditor`

My main question is, how to use `strip_tags or format_html` in a view only permission in django-admin page?

Admin Page for Announcement Model for superuser permissions:
[image]

Admin Page for Announcement Model for view only permission:
[image]

`model.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import date, datetime
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Activity(models.Model):
    what        = RichTextField(verbose_name=_('What'))
    where       = RichTextField(verbose_name=_('Where'))
    when        = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('When'))
    why         = RichTextField(verbose_name=_('Why'))
    who         = RichTextField(verbose_name=_('Who'))
    created_on  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author      = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Author'))
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Activity Announcements')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Activity Announcements')

    def __str__(self):
        from django.utils.html import strip_tags
        return '%s' % (strip_tags(self.what))
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .models import *

from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Activity)
class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    inlines = [ParticipantsInline, Aar_uploadInline]
    list_display = ('__str__','created_on',)
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj:
            form.base_fields['what'].initial = format_html(obj.what)
        return form
```

`Error`

```
KeyError at /admin/activity_announcements/activity/1/change/
'what'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/activity_announcements/activity/1/change/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'what'
Exception Location: /app/activity_announcements/admin.py, line 29, in get_form
Python Executable:  /py/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.9
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 21 Oct 2022 12:24:19 +0800
```

This is in the django-admin using django-jazzmin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the `def get_form()` function and use `format_html()` or `mark_safe()` inside as you say.

Something like that:

```
class MyAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .........
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if obj:
            form.base_fields['my_richtextfield_1'].initial = format_html(obj.my_richtextfield_1)
        return form
```

Comment: I believe that's how you do it in a template. in this case, I am using the django-admin site.

Comment: You are right. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: This gives me `keyerror 'what'` on `form.base_fieds['what'].initial`. I have similar `get_form` on other model, but it does not give a `keyerror`.

Comment: Could you share all the error code?

Comment: I'll update the question to include the code I have. thanks

Comment: already updated the question with additional details.

Comment: I don't know why, can you change `is obj:` to `is obj and obj.what:`?

Comment: already did that, maybe that has something with the `ckeditor` `richtextfield`.

Comment: or maybe, it cannot detect the `richtextfield` because I am displaying it as label?

Comment: After some digging, the `view only permission` render the fields as `readonly fields`, maybe that's what the cause of the error.